# SAML library/component for .NET

Tags: .net, saml

Can anyone recommend libraries for generating SAML assertions for a federated sign-on implementation in .NET.  It would be ideal if it was integrated with the ASP.NET membership API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ended up setting up a test using the ComponentSpace SAML 2.0 component.  Seems to be working pretty well so far.  It's nice that they have a free trial version.

http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this: http://saml2.codeplex.com

It's a fork of OIOSAML.NET for more general purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [Safewhere SAML 2.0 for ASP.NET](http://www.safewhere.net/Documents/Safewhere%20SAML%202.0%20Brief.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of Googling which pointed me to [OIOSAML.NET](http://www.softwareborsen.dk/projekter/softwarecenter/brugerstyring/oiosaml.net)
From the website 
*.Net based toolkit with a SAML 2.0 reference implementation conforming to the Danish eGov OIOSAML 2.0 profile. It is used for federation in the Danish public sector*

Answer (score 1):

Consider https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices

I'm evaluating it right now and so far so good.

LGPL licensing.