# How to use the metadata file (saml2)

Tags: saml

I am working on a project that needs to be integrating SAML2.0. I was thrown into this project suddenly, i need to make it work. 
Here is the background: We have created the files and wanted Client Company to integrate using SAML2 to get to our web site. We have sent them the meta datafile.

Now the client company had sent their metadata file. I dont know how and what to do with that file. Any help will be appreciated.

ASP.NET, Framework 4.0

Answer (score 9):

The metadata file basically provides you information of your client. Such as entityID, credential, and so on. If it is an IdP then it also contain couple URLs so that you know where to send different request, e.g. login request, attribute query request. You need to give this metadata to your SAML component so that it know which client it should talk to.

Another main purpose is to establish a trust relationship between SP and IdP.

Comment: Thanks, Where should i provide that info. Sorry for being ignorant.

Comment: It depends on how you implemented you saml component

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of old question but I would like to add some additional information and resources for .NET.

SAML Metadata is used to exchange configuration information between Service Provider and Identity Provider and vice versa. The information can include:

- Binging location
- Organization name
- Contact Person
- Single Sign On Url
- Single Logout Url

The Metadata can be signed and encrypted so that the information is sent securely. The other side may need the corresponding public key to validate and decrypt it and then can be used to understand and establish the connection with the SP or IdP.

You can see some more info at the following blog posts:

- http://samlcomponent.net/constructing-saml-metadata-xml-for-single-sign-on-idp/
- http://samlcomponent.net/how-to-create-saml-metadata-xml-for-service-provider/

Answer (score 2):

Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) is a standard for logging users into applications based on their sessions in another context. This single sign-on (SSO) login standard has significant advantages over logging in using a username/password:

1.No need to type in credentials

2.No need to remember and renew passwords

3.No weak passwords

It is easy to manage all applications in one tree using SAML SSO login.

```
       How actually SAML works:
```

The user accesses the remote application using a link on an intranet, a bookmark, or similar and the application loads.

The application identifies the user’s origin (by application subdomain, user IP address, or similar) and redirects the user back to the identity provider, asking for authentication. This is the authentication request.

The user either has an existing active browser session with the identity provider or establishes one by logging into the identity provider.

The identity provider builds the authentication response in the form of an XML-document containing the user’s username or email address, signs it using an X.509 certificate, and posts this information to the service provider.

The service provider, which already knows the identity provider and has a certificate fingerprint, retrieves the authentication response and validates it using the certificate fingerprint.

The identity of the user is established and the user is provided with app access.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [metadata SAML 2.0 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf) to check what elements must be read by your implementation.

If you are looking for a SAML2 .Net Tookit, take a look to [this thread of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337495/saml-library-component-for-net)

Also take a look on SAML open source implementations to learn how others resolved this problem before:

- [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) (PHP implementation Idp/SP).   ([Metadata parser](http://simplesamlphp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/SAMLParser.php))
- Shibboleth   [IdP](http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-shib-idp2/trunk/) (Java) ([opensaml2](http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-shib-idp2/trunk/))   /   [SP](http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/cpp-opensaml/trunk/) (C)
- spring-security-saml: [SP](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml) (Java)   ([metadata files](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml/tree/master/saml2-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata))
- [Jboss](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.picketlink/picketlink-fed/2.0.1.final/org/picketlink/identity/federation/core/parsers/saml/metadata/SAMLEntitiesDescriptorParser.java) (Java)

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is nothing but the xml file containing all the information required by your SAML implementation to talk with host. you can extract information from this meta to get the desired information required. Like public/private keys.
I hope you are also using certificate to talk with host on secure manner.
This key is required for handshaking with unknown host system.